# Percentage of Bar chart

Tags: java, sql

I have done the following codes to create a bar chart with the data from DB, and save it as an JPEG file.

I wanted to add percentage value anywhere in the table,

```
 JDBCCategoryDataset dataset = new JDBCCategoryDataset("", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
                   "", "");
  String query = "SELECT std,id from table";
 dataset.executeQuery(query);
  JFreeChart chart =ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("Test", "Id", "Score",dataset,
   PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, true, true, true);
   ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File(""),chart,1280, 1024);
```

Please advise.

Comment: and what's going on with this code ? what are you expecting ? Why don't you provide a file name ?

Comment: The file name is there but I remove it in the discussion, the file is saved normally, with the X-axis and Y-axis, I just wanted to add the percetage somewhere in the chart.

Comment: @sofian-you want to calculate percentage based on what? Do you want to calculate % on table data.Or you are facing problem adding % in barchart?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that the value you are interested in is `std`.  To get the proportion, you can use:

```
SELECT std, id,
       std / sum(std) over () as proportion
from table
```

For the percentage, just multiply by 100:

```
SELECT std, id,
       100*std / sum(std) over () as percentage
from table
```

This is using a type of function called *analytic functions* in Oracle.